# jquery Autocomplete plugin working with older versions of the browsers but not new ones?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

i am using jquery Autocomplete plugin it is working fine in older versions of the browsers but in new version of the browsers it is not showing all the suggestions. i am using JSON to parse the data.is there any compatibility problems with json or with jquery plugin?

Comment: helps if you linked to the plug-in that you are using since there are tons of autocomplete ones out there. :)

Comment: Some code would be helpful in understanding the root cause. json is the standard way to get results back from server and it integrates well with jQuery autocomplete.

Comment: If it works in older browsers but not in newer ones, the problem is probably in your code (or maybe using a very old jQuery/jQuery UI).

Comment: @epascarello i am using jquery-ui-1.8.14.autocomplete.min.js plugin

Comment: @bazmegakapa i am using latest version of jquery only

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery Autocomplete working with older versions of the browsers but not new ones?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646620/jquery-autocomplete-working-with-older-versions-of-the-browsers-but-not-new-ones)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your JSON, I am guessing the JSON is not valid.

I will assume your JSON is missing double quotes around the keys.

```
[ 
    { 
        id: "Ficedula hypoleuca", 
        label : "Eurasian Pied Flycatcher", 
        value : "Eurasian Pied Flycatcher" 
    },
    ...
]
```

To be valid JSON, it needs the double quotes around the keys

```
[ 
    { 
        "id": "Ficedula hypoleuca", 
        "label": "Eurasian Pied Flycatcher", 
        "value": "Eurasian Pied Flycatcher" 
    },
    ...
]
```

Older browser do not support native [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). jQuery uses the native JSON parse method when available. The native parse is very strict when it comes to JSON syntax.

Comment: i am using correct notation as you shown above, i will explain bit clear about my problem. for example if i am typing keyword "an" or "ge" which should matches to the words like "anzahl","general" it is not happening, firebug is showing error like "bad controle character in a string literal". it is working fine for some other keywords but not for others. the whole is working in old browsers

Comment: this is the JSON format i am using                                                                                 { "list" : [ {"genericIndicatorId" : 100,"isActive" : false, "maxValue" : null, "minValue" : null, "modificationDate" : 1283904000000, "monotone" : 1, "name":"Abbau", "old_name" : "abbau_change_delete_imac", "position" : 2, "systemGraphics" : "000000", "unitId" : 1, "valueType" : 1, "description" : "Abbau", "weight" : 1 }]}